# What's wrong with this proof that $\text{Isom}(\mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{R}) \cong \text{Isom}(\mathbb{S}^2) \times \text{Isom}(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I've been trying to prove that $\text{Isom}(\mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{R}) \cong \text{Isom}(\mathbb{S}^2) \times \text{Isom}(\mathbb{R})$ and I think I've come up with a simple proof, but it's so simple that I'm almost certain I made a mistake somewhere. Here goes:

> Let $F: \mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{R}$ be an isometry. For each $(\hat{x}, y) \in \mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{R}$, with $\hat{x} = (x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb{S}^2$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$, writing $F(\hat{x}, y) = (A(\hat{x}), B(y))$, we want to prove that $A: \mathbb{S}^2 \to \mathbb{S}^2$ and $B: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are isometries, that is, for any $s, t \in \mathbb{S}^2$ we have $\langle A(s) - A(t), A(s)- A(t) \rangle = \langle s - t, s -t \rangle$ and for all $n, m \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $|B(n) - B(m)| =  |n - m|$.
>
> Well, since $F$ is an isometry of $\mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{R}$, given $s, t \in \mathbb{S}^2$, it must be true that $\langle F(s, 0) - F(t, 0),F(s, 0) - F(t, 0) \rangle = \langle(s - t, 0), (s-t, 0) \rangle$. It follows that:
>
> $$\|A(s) - A(t)\|^2 + (B(0) - B(0))^2 = \|s-t\|^2 + (0-0)^2$$
>
> and therefore $\langle A(s) - A(t), A(s)- A(t) \rangle = \langle s - t, s -t \rangle$, as we wanted to prove. The proof that $B$ is an isometry is analagous.

What's the catch here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give a sketch that every isometry $F:S^2\times \mathbb{R}\to S^2\times \mathbb{R}$ is of the form $F(p,y)=(A(p),B(y)).$

Fix arbitrary $p\in S^2$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}$. Let $q\in S^2$ and $r\in \mathbb{R}$ be given by $(q,r)=F(p,y)$. Observe that the tangent space at $(p,y)$ splits as an orthogonal sum
\begin{equation*}
T_{(p,y)}(S^2\times\mathbb{R})=T_pS^2\oplus T_y\mathbb{R}
\end{equation*}
and similarly
\begin{equation*}
T_{(q,r)}(S^2\times\mathbb{R})=T_qS^2\oplus T_r\mathbb{R}.
\end{equation*}
Recall that $(dF)_{(p,y)}:T_pS^2\oplus T_y\mathbb{R}\to T_qS^2\oplus T_r\mathbb{R}$ is an isometry between vector spaces. Observe that 
\begin{equation*}
(dF)_{(p,y)}\big(T_pS^2\big)\subset T_qS^2,
\end{equation*}
since otherwise $F$ would map some periodic geodesics to non-periodic geodesics. Since $T_pS^2$ and $T_qS^2$ have the same dimension, we even get
\begin{equation*}
(dF)_{(p,y)}\big(T_pS^2\big)=T_qS^2
\end{equation*}
by the injectivity of $(dF)_{(p,y)}$. As $(dF)_{(p,y)}$ is an isometry, 
\begin{equation*}
(dF)_{(p,y)}\big(T_y\mathbb{R}\big)=T_r\mathbb{R}
\end{equation*}
follows from the orthogonal decompositions of the tangent spaces. Hence we get a decomposition
\begin{equation*}
(dF)_{(p,y)}=a\oplus b
\end{equation*}
for some isometries $a:T_pS^2\to T_qS^2$ and $b: T_y\mathbb{R}\to T_r\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, for any $v\in T_pM$ and $c,t\in \mathbb{R}$ we have
\begin{equation*}
F\big(\exp_p(tv),y+ct\big)=\Big(\exp_q\big(ta(v)\big),r+tb(c)\Big).
\end{equation*}
Can you conclude from here?

Comment: No, I can't, sorry. As of yet I know very little about riemannian geometry, so I would really appreciate it if you finished the argument so I could come back to it later and study it with the attention it deserves. One more question: do you think your argument could be generalized to show that any isometry $F$ of $\mathbb{H}^2 \times \mathbb{R}$ is also of the form $F(p, y) = (A(p), B(y))$ for all $p \in \mathbb{H}^2$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$? If you could, I'd also appreciate some references on riemannian geometry other than do Carmo.

Comment: My argument can‘t directly be used when $S^2$ is replaced by the hyperbolic plane because I used that all geodesics in $S^2$ are periodic. Maybe the result still holds in the case of the upper half plane, but it would require more careful analysis. I think I could do it, but it wouldn’t be very short. If you are also interested in that case it might be better to post a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not every map $F: \mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{R}$ can be written in the form $F(\hat{x}, y) = (A(\hat{x}), B(y))$.  As an analogy, consider a map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to itself;  is it true that every such map can be written in the form $F(x,y) = (f(x), g(y))$?

Comment: I think though that the isometries will have to be of this form. Perhaps we can prove an isometry will have to preserve the bundle structure?

Comment: I see now that it isn't the case for general maps (but I agree with @AlfredYerger, my intuition tells me isometries should all be of that form but I can't prove why yet). I should write $F(\hat{x}, y) = (A(\hat{x}, y) , B(\hat{x}, y) ) $, right? Also, can you tell me if the mistake you pointed out is the only one in the "proof"?

Comment: You can use the exponential map to show that each isometry $F$ is of the form $F(x,y)=(A(x),B(y)).$